# how to compare ndarrays in python

Tags: python

I have an array of ndarray like

```
array([ ndarray[ 3,  2,  1], ndarray [ 2,  4,  5], ndarray[ 1 ,  3,  6]])
```

I want to find max in 1th,2th and 3th cell between ndarrays that is mean :

```
Result = [3,4,6]
```

(3 is max between `array[0][0]` and `array[1][0]` and `array[2][0]` )

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy.max` with axis 0 :

```
>>> A=np.array([[ 3, 2, 1],[ 2, 4, 5],[ 1 , 3, 6]])
>>> np.max(A,axis=0)
array([3, 4, 6])
```

Comment: or use the method on the array instance `A.max(axis=0)`

Comment: @wim Yes, That's a nice way too.